# Modifying Live Call through REST API, how to pass parameters to Twiml URL

Tags: twilio

I want to pass some parameters through to twiml script that will be executed as a result of a call update https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state. The parameters of a get are not being passed through.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio employee here. An HTTP GET request will not work, you need to make a HTTP POST instead.

Look at the XML and JSON [examples](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#examples) on the doc page that you linked.